# Unsure about designing an ultra wide band antenna

Tags: antenna, pcb-antenna

So, a bit of background, I have designed and measured some antennas in college so I have a decent theoretical grasp of the subject, but they were optimized for a narrow band usage and certain frequency.

I am now doing my own home project which would include an internal antenna that is supposed to be ultra wide band (from 30 MHz to 3 GHz) done on a PCB. Online resources are scarce and I do not know how to get started so that it haves any semblance of an actual antenna.

What I am actually looking for is any tips and tricks for a person who already has some understanding of a more "typical" antenna designs, I am comfortable with sacraficing efficiency for more bandwidth. If you could recommend me any literature witch discusses UWB internal antenna design, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a directional antenna that you want to build? In that case I would go with a LOGPER type of construction.

Comment: @StefanWyss I was considering it, but I have doubts if the antenna can be ponting at the right direction all the time, I would consider building both omnidirectional and directional variants and test them both.

Comment: I have never seen an omnidirectional antenna with such a high bandwidth. Good luck.

Comment: Have you searched in Google for "uwb antennas" and then pressed the **Images** tab? I then see **MANY** examples of UWB antennas with strange and interesting patterns. It is unclear though what the actual bandwidth of there antennas is though.

Comment: Why do you want an antenna to cover such a wide frequency range? What's the application?

Comment: I recommend using @Bimpelrekkie's approach. I would also note that if you are unconstrained and only need a single antenna element you have a lot of flexibility in bandwidth and most likely will be some variant on a monopole. Down to 30 MHz might be tough. UWB patterns will be somewhat wonky at different frequencies.

Comment: @StefanWyss i have explored LOGPER PCB designs and it seems that dimensions whould have to be too large for PCB usage because of the lower frequency range. 30 MHz seems simply too low for electrically small antennae.

Comment: Yes, lambda/4 is 2.5 Meters at 30 MHz.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a good answer. But once the internal antena of my cell phone broken, so it showed no signal. I did cut a same size stip from a copper plate and soldered. I got full signal strenth. It was about 2 cm. I think you can start from a cell phone to experiment at GHz range because it will show the signal strenth. I dont talk about wave equation , because you said that you know all that. Good luck!!
[image]

Comment: Such an antenna as you have drawn is for a relatively narrow frequency range.  The question is about how to make an antenna that covers a very large range.  Specifically, from 30 MHz to 3 GHz.  Your cell phone sqiuggle covers only a tiny fraction of the required range.

Comment: @upali this is a meander antenna and its designed to be a narrow band antenna, so it doesnt quite fit my design requirements.

Comment: Thank you JRE. You are correct. But every antenna has a resonance frequency regarding to ti's length. Some one else may give a good answer. But if there is a method, already it should be in the market.

Comment: Ok Jakov. Wait untill some one answer.